# Записать массив числовых значений в таблицу состоящую из инпутов

Tags: javascript

Помогите решить такую задачу. 
Имеется массив, состоящий из 9 числовых значений например: `var readyArray = [1, 0, 4, 2, 0, 1, 6, 2, 0];` Нужно записать данный массив в таблицу, состоящую из инпутов, таблица имеет определенное количество срок и столбцов, а именно 3 столбца и 3 строки (3x3):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Я новенький в этом, получается нужно проходить циклом по строкам, а потом по столбцам? Помогите пожалуйста, может есть примеры или просто направьте меня в нужную строну.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var readyArray = [1, 0, 4, 2, 0, 1, 6, 2, 0];
var html = "";
var index = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    html += `<input type="text" value="${readyArray[index++]}"/>`;
  }
  html += "<br/>";
}
document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = html;
```

```css
#container input {
  width: 50px;
  margin: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Это если фиксированное количество инпутов

```js
const inputs = [...document.querySelectorAll(".input__table input")];
var readyArray = [1, 0, 4, 2, 0, 1, 6, 2, 0];

inputs.forEach((input, index) => {
  input.value = readyArray[index]
})
```

```css
.input__table{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 320px;
}
.input__table input{
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="input__table">
  <input type="text" value="">
  <input type="text" value="">
  <input type="text" value="">
  <input type="text" value="">
  <input type="text" value="">
  <input type="text" value="">
  <input type="text" value="">
  <input type="text" value="">
  <input type="text" value="">
</div>
```